# Not being able to post more than once every 20 mins means I can't file all my bug reports easily

Tags: feature-request, rate-limiting, bug-reports

I'm trying to be a helpful citizen and file a whole bunch of bug reports for the Android app. But the 20-minute limit is getting in my way; really unhelpful for everyone involved. I've got lots of tabs open ready to go...

Comment: Given you can only post once every 20 minutes, you've submitted 2 straight questions that are "bugs" about bug reports.  If you have "lots of tabs open ready to go", why did you waste 40 minutes submitting the bugs about bug reports?

Comment: @psubsee2003 I didn't waste 40 minutes, I spent them. I assume other people hit the same issues; as I say, I'm trying to be a helpful citizen.

Comment: It's not a bug though, you are making a feature request to change the behavior of the app.  Rate limiting is an intentional feature.  The App uses a public API and therefore requires rate limiting to protect the site from someone spamming the site via the API.

Comment: One man's bug is another man's feature request. It's not a cool feature that I wish the site had; it's existing behaviour of the site that's contrary to my reasonable expectations/desires as a user. That's a bug, intentional or not.

Comment: You and I disagree about what a bug is then.  To me bugs are unintentional side effects and not design decisions.

Comment: To me bugs are deficiencies, feature requests are improvements. This is something that actively frustrated me during my use of the software - it's something that should get "fixed", not "implemented".

Comment: We're just going to have to agree to disagree, but historically, the SE community tends to favor the "unintentional side effects" definition.

Comment: If designer intended X, X happened, you don't like X --> feature request. If designer intended X, Y happened, you don't like Y but might like X --> Bug report.

Comment: It's not down to opinion, the term bug has [a definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bug)... ask yourself if it's really necessary to post all your feature requests back to back?

Comment: I can't judge the value of the contributions in the case at hand, but it shouldn't matter, either. People have been actively asked to submit their feedback to the new app on Meta, no? So putting up such an obstacle seems inane.

Comment: Congratulations, you are no longer rate limited.  As identified by the [Complete Rate Limiting Guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide), your recent contributions have been valued enough that you are no longer limited to 1 post every 20 minutes.

Answer (score 4):

This seems a fair point in general.

If you ask for feeedback on a new app:

> So if there’s something you’d like to see in the app, let us know on Meta under the ‘android-app’ tag

(there's even a link.)

You shouldn't rate limit questions like this for new users. Feature requests and bug reports are prone to coming up in bursts, during the initial use of the app.

Comment: I agree to a point.  It should take time to write a good question (even on meta).  IMO, its not just throwing some words in a text box, so the limit does help reduce that for new users who don't know this.  The level of this specific users contributions this morning certainly support some level of rate limiting.  Maybe 20 minutes is too long, but I think it should be at least 10 min as I think it takes that long to put together a good question with the appropriate back (links, images, steps to reproduce, pros & cons, etc).

Comment: @psubsee2003 I agree with you for Meta's normal day-to-day operations, but if you *actively* ask the public to contribute their reports on a newly launched product, then you can't have them run into a limit like this. It's like a slap in the face, and comes across as arrogant beyond words. What about people who are in the habit of preparing their contributions elsewhere (like in Word)?... Meta is perfectly capable of handling whatever low-quality content comes in with the instruments at its disposal

Comment: Very true, and maybe the limit should be temporarily suspended only for posts using the android app tag so users can file their bug reports.